# Grocery crud hidden field and set relation didnt work together

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have a problem with grocery crud hidden field and set relation .

My code is

```
$crud->set_relation('created_by','users','user_name'); 
$crud->edit_fields('title', 'description', 'created_by');
$crud->change_field_type('created_by', 'hidden', $this->user_id);
```

Here i want to store user_id as created by in hidden form. But problem is that created_by field is still visible in my view page. when I cut off set_relation then created_by field is hidden. What's problem ? plz help me

Answer (score 1):

```
$state = $crud->getState();
if ($state === 'list') {
  $crud->set_relation('created_by','users','user_name'); 
}
$crud->edit_fields('title', 'description', 'created_by');
$crud->change_field_type('created_by', 'hidden', $this->user_id);
```

Comment: You should consider adding some explanatory sentences, this increases the value of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below coding

```
$crud->change_field_type('created_by', 'hidden', $this->user_id);
```

to

```
$crud->field_type('created_by', 'hidden', $this->user_id);
```

Comment: Not working this method, I have another field which is hidden by this change_field_type but only created_by field is not working